# python/django - [u''] is not empty

Tags: python, django

Sorry for silly question first of all.

I am getting a list of user inputs of same type like:

```
<input name="booknames" type="text">
<input name="booknames" type="text">
<input name="booknames" type="text">
```

and in viws:

```
if request.POST.getlist('booknames'):
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

even if no user inputs there, i am getting `yes`. I printed the list, I get `[u'']` which is empty.

am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[u'']` is not empty. It's a list with one element, the empty string. Lists are considered `True` in a boolean context if they have any elements, which that list does. If you want to see whether your list has any non-empty elements, try `any(request.POST.getlist('booknames'))`.

Comment: do you know how to ``any`` in django template?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to do that, but it would be easy to write a `|any` custom filter that you could then use in `{% if .. %}` expressions.

Comment: @doniyor: The fact that an collection of empty collections is not empty is pretty much fundamental to most of mathematics. For example, the first three natural numbers are `{}`, `{{}}`, `{{{}}, {}}`, …